# Not be able to update the list view, after removing some items

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have to update the list after optimizing the running apps ....

```
   m_optimizeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
        launchProgressRing(OptimizationActivity.this);
            listAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

Killing the running process in a seprate thread....

```
    public void launchProgressRing(Context ctx){
    final ProgressDialog opt_proDialog=new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    opt_proDialog.setTitle("Please wait...");
    opt_proDialog.setMessage("Optimizing power draining apps...");
    opt_proDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    opt_proDialog.show();
    opt_proDialog.setCancelable(false);
    new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            //TODO: optimize apps
            m_cPowerDrainingApps.killBgRunningProcesses(runningAppsList);
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(1500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    opt_proDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

listAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged() is not working ,don't know why ???

Comment: put your listview.setAdapter(your adapter) in onResume() method if not work then put your Activity code.

Comment: how you change data in your listadapter? does the thread do anything regarding this?

Comment: @Pooya .   m_cPowerDrainingApps.killBgRunningProcesses(runningAppsList) this is responsible for data change....it is removing some processes from the list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I suggest is to use AsyncTask to do the job. AsyncTask has two good methods for you:

- doInBackground: which you can put most of the background tasks in there
- onPostExecute : which you can put the logic of what needs to be done when the background task has finished its job.

So your code should look like this:

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>{

   private ListAdapter mAdapter;

   public BackgroundTask(ListAdapter adapter)
   {
      mAdapter = adapter
   }

   public Void doInBackground (Void... params)
   {
      //define m_cPowerDrainingApps somewhere
      m_cPowerDrainingApps.killBgRunningProcesses(runningAppsList);
      try
      {
           Thread.sleep(1500);
      } catch (InterruptedException e)
      {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public Void onPostExecute (Void... params)
   {
      //do your UI things
      mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
}
```

and then run this with:

```
new BackgroundTask(listAdapter).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Handler and its postDelayed method to invalidate the list's adapter as follows:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler()
handler.postDelayed( new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        handler.postDelayed( this, 60 * 1000 );
    }
}, 60 * 1000 );
```

You must only update UI in the main (UI) thread.